# Who should the new moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

As AVP is rapidly nearing being re-branded to specifically fit the Video community, it's time to think about the users that can lead this site and community through a renewed beta phase. It's the job of moderators to step in occasionally and do what the community *can't*, and to act as a liaison between this community and Stack Exchange. These three folks will have our ear, and will work with us to make sure the needs of this community are being met.

Once the transition is finished, the [existing moderator team](https://video.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) will remain moderators on Sound Design SE alone. Video needs a few great users to step up! They're currently moderators on both sites to help with the migrations and transition.

Moderators should be:

- Consistently patient and fair in their interactions with new users
- Able to give an hour or two of their time each week to moderate
- Interested in having the responsibility of being a moderator
- Knowledgeable in the major tags to the point that they can judge the quality of a post, though high reputation is definitely not a requirement

If you're interested in leading the Video Production Stack Exchange community, or think that another user would be a great fit for the job, nominate yourself (or them) as an answer to this question to let us know you're interested.

When nominating, link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta). Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

If the nomination was posted by a 3rd-party, the nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer to add that they accept the nomination and optionally write something about themselves.

While votes on nominations are a guiding factor in our decision, we don't make our selections based on votes alone. We might also approach some users that weren't nominated or didn't nominate to see if they might be interested, based on their previous participation.

For more information about the Stack Exchange moderation philosophy and the initial moderator selection process, see here:

- [A theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Moderator pro tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

Good luck!

**Update**

AJ and Rory have accepted and been appointed, but we still need one more moderator to complete the team. Would you like to help lead this community, or know of a user that would do a good job? Let us know in an answer below!

Due to the recent split from Sound, it's rather difficult for me to go through the list of users and contact folks individually, as I can't be certain that some didn't move the bulk of their activity over to Sound Design (though Video remains extremely active post-split). Hence - if you'd like to be considered, I really need to hear from you!

Answer (score 9):

I nominate [AJ Henderson](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/2836/aj-henderson)!

AJ not only has the highest rep on the site, but has also been helping with moderation type issues.  Often I have seen a comment from AJ on a post in the review Queue guiding the user in the right direction.

Comment: AJ Was also a _major_ help during the migration of questions to Sound Design, which should be noted somewhere just for general purposes because it's the right thing to do :)

Comment: Thanks for the nomination.  I would certainly be more than happy to do this.  I have moderated a number of other online communities in the past and don't plan on going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: I guess I should add a little about me as well.  I have been active with Stack Exchange for almost a year and a half.  During that time, I have been a top contributor on IT Security, Photography and Audio/Video Production.  I have a long history of working on the review queues and am active in the communities around Photography and IT Security.  I want to see Video develop a core community like that of IT Security and Photography.

Comment: While I have not previously moderated in an official capacity on SE, I have been both a moderator for the IRC network Dorksnet, which had around 600 to 700 users when I was active as well as having helped moderate multiple gaming communities online.  I put a heavy emphasis on trying to make sure that I understand where all parties are coming from when disputes unfortunately occur and strive my best to bring peace, if not understanding between parties.

Comment: I believe that moderation on SE involves helping the community along and building it up.  It involves encouraging the community itself to take up the banner and move forward as a group.  The community is best able to determine its direction and it is the job of moderators to help it in that direction and try to avoid running in to anything along the way.

Comment: AJ's access is now enabled, while we wait for the third candidate to come through. I normally don't do it this way, but since he's actively working on finishing up the split related stuff, he could really use better tools in his hands so he can just _do it_ instead of waiting for me or Rory. Welcome aboard, AJ! There will be a formal post welcoming all three, once we know who the third is going to be.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate [Rory](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/674/dr-mayhem) assuming he isn't too busy with all the other sites he works with.  I know he is also video focused and does a great job on all the sites I've known him as a moderator on.

**Rory edit:**

I am happy to accept this nomination.

I joined AVP 800 days ago, as I have worked in audio and video since the mid-nineties - initially on a professional basis, as a pre-sales engineer for Silicon Graphics, demoing Alias Wavefront and video editing suites, and more recently on an enthusiastic amateur basis for my rock band :-)

As a Moderator on a few Stack Exchange sites already, I have a good grasp of the necessary activities to help sites develop, stay tidy and clean, and to calm the odd anger/frustration without taking things too personally. The sites I moderate range from the very active Security Stack Exchange, to some of the much smaller betas, like Personal Productivity.

For the Audio/Video transition, Tim asked me to help out with sorting, clean up of tags etc, and while there is quite an effort required to fully merge the Audio culture with the SOund Design culture, here we are much more in a business as usual mode, so I know I can make time to moderate, and to continue to contribute.

I am as patient and fair as I can be with managing disagreements and new users' challenges, and I am known for trying to clean up comments and answers. I am also known for making mistakes on occasion, and accept challenge gracefully - remember a mod is only here to help the community, so when we get it wrong we need to accept that fact.

I set up the [Security SE blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com), and while I still don't have as many volunteer contributors as I would like, I try and arrange for reasonably regular publications.

Answer (score 3):

[Bart Arondson](http://stackexchange.com/users/1307735/bart-arondson?tab=accounts) is multi-disciplinary, active on the SE network as a whole and is active in the review queue.

Comment: Although I'm honored by the nomination, I don't think being a moderator at Video.SE is something for me. I don't have much knowledge of video production (besides using Google effectively) and haven't been very active on this SE.